# setbuf only affects stdio calls, not system calls?

Tags: c, pipe, stdio

I'm trying to get a deeper grasp at how buffering works in `C` and `stdio`, and I came across something I find interesting. I read [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) article but I want to confirm I'm understanding correctly.

When I use `fgets`, set the input buffering to 3 bytes (`stdbuf -i3`) and examine the `strace`, I see the reads are happening in groups of 3 characters, which I expect:

```
read(0, "hel", 3)                       = 3
read(0, "lo\n", 3)                      = 3
...
```

If I still use `stdbuf` but this time I do `read(2)` system calls instead, it reads the entirety at once (up to 4096 bytes):

```
read(0, "hello\nworld!\n\n", 4096)      = 14
```

So it ignores the `stdbuf` call.

This makes me completely rethink `stdio` buffering. Does `stdio` maintain its own buffer essentially, and `stdbuf -i3` is saying to read into that buffer 3 bytes at a time from the main pipe buffer in the kernel? I thought doing `stdbuf -i0` would make the capacity somehow of the pipe not be able to hold more than one byte (i.e. `write(2)` calls would block after 1 byte from the process sending the `stdout` to the processes's unbuffered `stdin`).

So would it be correct to say that there's 2 buffers sitting on top of the actual pipe buffer that further buffer `stdout` and `stdin`? And `setbuf` only controls those two buffers, rather than modifying any properties about the kernel pipe buffer. So setting `stdin` to be an `n` byte buffer means that it will keep `n` bytes before going back to the kernel to do a `read` system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffering only exists within libc, the functions you call from stdio. There is no buffering at syscall interface. If you make a system call (using e.g. `read` or `write`), there is typically very little that the libc wrappers do before calling the kernel.

The [documentation for `stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) says

> `command` must start with the name of a program that ... uses the ISO C FILE streams for input/output (note the programs `dd` and `cat` don’t do that),

This is because [`stdbuf` works](https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/stdbuf.c) by pre-loading a library into the target program which changes the buffering mode (in its libc). A program that makes direct system calls is unaffected.

`stdbuf` is not changing the size of the pipe buffer within the kernel. This buffer is unrelated to the buffering provided by libc.

---

> Does stdio maintain its own buffer essentially, and stdbuf -i3 is saying to read into that buffer 3 bytes at a time from the main pipe buffer in the kernel?

Yes. Libc provides buffers for the stdio.h `FILE` streams.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be correct to say then that `stdin` is directed at the `libc` buffer (which flows to the pipe buffer), essentially, where `STDIN_FILENO` (or fd 0) is directed directly to the write end of the pipe buffer, bypassing the `libc` buffer?

Comment: The kernel might and does have its own buffers!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this means I can’t guarantee unbuffered reads or writes when making syscalls? It sounds like from what I’ve read a big difference between STDIN and STDIN_FILENO is the former is buffered while the latter is not. But maybe they just mean that the former is buffered by the stdio later?

Comment: Yes... The kernel for example always has had buffers for pipes and terminals. Even if you run a program like `cat` without arguments, it *cannot* receive what's being written from terminal until newline or ctrl+d because the kernel buffers that... And for pipes there is a 32-128K buffer inside the kernel

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks! So to clarify, this means that when I do a write syscall, it’s possible that the data wouldn’t be available on the read end of the pipe immediately? If this is indeed the case, how would one make it such that all writes in a program are made available immediately to the read end of the pipe?

Comment: The buffering usually means that the data *is* available immediately, however, but that `write` returns is not a sign of the other end having read the message.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala certainly. So here is where I’m a bit confused, if writes are immediately available to the pipe’s read end, and the terminal were to make a write syscall on every character written out, wouldn’t a program blocking on a read call on the receiving end of the pipe (like cat) get that data immediately? Or is it that the write syscall from the terminal only happen upon an EOF/newline?